# How to store an input (TextCtrl) into a variable, process it through some code-lines and show the outputs in another window in wxPython?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, wxtextctrl

I built a script that find a book by pertinence (output) given a quote (input). Now I want to create the GUI of this script and I decided to use wxPython. I would like a basic GUI, where the user can write the phrase in a text bar, then push a button storing the string he entered in a variable. In this way, I can use the variable as input for the algorithm that find the book associated with the entered phrase, showing the title and author as output in a second window.

I built the code that allows me to create the GUI and to store the phrase in the variable `var`. Now I don't know how to proceed, because I can't access `var` outside the class. Here the code and the image of the GUI:

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        my_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        my_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        manual = wx.StaticText(panel, label='1) Inserisci la citazione --> ')
        font_manual = wx.Font(10, wx.SCRIPT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        manual.SetFont(font_manual)
        hbox.Add(manual)
        manual2 = wx.StaticText(panel, label='2) Clicca sul logo Bibliovago --> ')
        font_manual2 = wx.Font(10, wx.SCRIPT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        manual2.SetFont(font_manual2)
        hbox.Add(manual2)
        manual3 = wx.StaticText(panel, label='3) Buona lettura')
        font_manual3 = wx.Font(10, wx.SCRIPT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        manual3.SetFont(font_manual3)
        hbox.Add(manual3)
        my_sizer.Add(hbox,0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        my_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()

        istr = wx.StaticText(panel, label='Inserisci una citazione')
        font_istr = wx.Font(14, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        istr.SetFont(font_istr)
        my_sizer.Add(istr, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)

        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        my_sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)        

        logo_button = wx.Bitmap('LOGO.png')
        self.my_btn = wx.BitmapButton(panel,-1,logo_button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SavePhrase, self.my_btn)
        my_sizer.Add(self.my_btn, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5) 


        panel.SetSizer(my_sizer)

        my_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()

    def SavePhrase(self, event):
        var = self.text_ctrl.GetValue()       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frm = MyFrame(None, title='BiblioZam', size = (600,400))
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[GUI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VaAP.png)

Should I use my algorithm inside the class as a function? Or there is another way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use classes and you need to access something across methods inside a class, then you need to create the variable by prepending it with `self`. So in `SavePhrase`, you need to create `var` as `self.var` if other parts of the class need access to it

If you want to show the results in a separate window, then I would create a new `wx.Frame` instance inside of `SavePhrase` and pass it your `var`. Then you don't need to call it `self.var` unless something else in `MyFrame` itself needs to access `var`.

Here is an example:

```
import wx

class OtherFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    Class used for creating frames other than the main one
    """

    def __init__(self, var, title='Other Frame', parent=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, title=title)
        self.var = var
        print('var = {}'.format(var))
        self.Show()


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        my_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        my_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        manual = wx.StaticText(panel, label='1) Inserisci la citazione --> ')
        font_manual = wx.Font(10, wx.SCRIPT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        manual.SetFont(font_manual)
        hbox.Add(manual)
        manual2 = wx.StaticText(panel, label='2) Clicca sul logo Bibliovago --> ')
        font_manual2 = wx.Font(10, wx.SCRIPT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        manual2.SetFont(font_manual2)
        hbox.Add(manual2)
        manual3 = wx.StaticText(panel, label='3) Buona lettura')
        font_manual3 = wx.Font(10, wx.SCRIPT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        manual3.SetFont(font_manual3)
        hbox.Add(manual3)
        my_sizer.Add(hbox,0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        my_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()

        istr = wx.StaticText(panel, label='Inserisci una citazione')
        font_istr = wx.Font(14, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        istr.SetFont(font_istr)
        my_sizer.Add(istr, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)

        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        my_sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        logo_button = wx.Bitmap('LOGO.png')
        self.my_btn = wx.BitmapButton(panel,-1,logo_button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SavePhrase, self.my_btn)
        my_sizer.Add(self.my_btn, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)


        panel.SetSizer(my_sizer)

        my_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()

    def SavePhrase(self, event):
        var = self.text_ctrl.GetValue()
        frame = OtherFrame(var=var)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frm = MyFrame(None, title='BiblioZam', size = (600,400))
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Now your other frame can use `var` as needed to generate the result. Note that if generating the result takes a long time, you might want to move that generation step into a thread so it doesn't block your GUI's main loop and cause it to appear to hang.

You might also find this article of mine helpful - http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/10/19/wxpython-how-to-open-a-second-window-frame/

Comment: what do you mean with "then I would create a new wx.Frame instance inside of SavePhrase"? I am sorry but I am new with this kind of things could you post an example code? So, If I well understood you suggest to create the other frame and process 'var' inside 'SavePhrase'. In order to process 'var' I should use another function that I created, do you know if I can define this function outside the class? Or should I define it outside? Thank you

Comment: Sure. I just added an example of what I am talking about